# How do I convert the fields in one row into columns?

Tags: ms-access, pivot, crosstab

I have a table with columns such as:

```
          Cost     Rate

          Repair   12
          Repair   223
          Wear     1000    
          Wear     666
          Fuel     500
          Repair   600
          Fuel     450
          Wear     400
```

and I want this data as columns(Repair,Wear,Fuel) as:

```
         Repair    Wear   Fuel
           825     2066    950
```

How could I do this using an MS Access Query?

Comment: Sorry I have no ready to use solution to your question, however you maybe want to lookout for the word "transposing" + the database you are using. I think in MSSQL/Oracle this can be achieved with PIVOT/UNPIVOT. Welcome, nice question and good luck!

Comment: By now you've probably figured out how to do it. So just update the question with the correct commands, or select an answer.

Answer (score 5):

While there's a traditional SQL solution for this that is pretty kludgy, reading [this page](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=25) alerted me to the fact that MS Access has a [TRANSFORM ... PIVOT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010322771033.aspx) statement you probably should look into and use to do this.

I can't be certain but it should look like:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Items].[Rate]) AS SumOfRate 
SELECT [Items].[Costs] 
FROM Items 
GROUP BY [Items].[Costs] 
PIVOT Format([Items].[Costs]);
```

And it can get fancier than this. E.G.

```
PIVOT Format([Items].[month],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb",...,"Nov","Dec");
```

Comment: If people using Access would just use the FRICKING user interface, they'd know that these kinds of things are possible. There's a frigging wizard to do this for you -- it's called a CROSSTAB.

Answer (score 3):

untested but

```
SELECT
(SELECT  sum(rate)  from mytable where cost = 'Repair') AS Repair ,
(SELECT  sum(rate) from mytable where cost = 'Wear') AS Wear,
(SELECT  sum(rate) from mytable wherecost = 'Fuel') AS Fuel
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this query

```
select 
sum(select rate from yourtable where cost = 'Repair') "Repair", 
sum(select rate from yourtable where cost = 'Wear') "Wear", 
sum(select rate from yourtable where cost = 'Fuel') "Fuel" 
from dual
```

if you are using Oracle

otherwise, if any other database engine, you can make a quick statement right before this one

```
create table dual (x char)

insert into dual values "x"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a Crosstab query. There is a wizard in the Access Queries window that will walk you through creating one.  Just click the New Query button and select the Crosstab Query Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the data you need:

```
select cost, sum(rate)

from mytable

group by cost
```

and then you can present it whichever way you like.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..but i want the rows(repair,wear,fuel) as columns

Comment: SQL doesn't support it. (There's no reason it should...) You have to do this programmatically afterwards.

Comment: @gs you are right in so far as this approach often can be seen as an attempt to fix something that went wrong in the modeling phase. Nevertheless in my opinion this request is not that uncommon and should be part of a modern standard. For example all those data warehouse guys need this very often.